# jquery .change() $ajax() javascript variable issue

Tags: jquery

I'm really not sure where the problem is, but the first two `<select>`+`event` pairs work, but the third doesn't, and it's almost exactly the same as the second.

The variable "firmName" resolves to a single-word string and if I manually replace the variable with its value, the function works (but it is triggered onload instead of by the change() it's binded to): http://www.frende.me/invoiceBuilder.php

```
<select id="firm" name="firm"></select>
<select id="client" name="client"></select>
<select id="project" name="project"></select>
<select id="task" name="task"></select>
<p id="results"></p>
<script>
window.onload = (function(){
    $.ajax({
        /* populates the first <select> with <options> */
    });
});

$("#firm").change(function () {
    var firmName = "";
    $("#firm option:selected").each(function () {
        firmName += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '_resources/db_clientworklog_selectField.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: ({
            table: firmName,
            column: "client",
            }),
        success: function(data){
            $("#client").html(data);
         }
    });
})
.change();

$("#client").change(function () {
    var firmName = $("#firm").val();
    $("#results").text(firmName);
    $("#client option:selected").each(function () {
        clientName += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '_resources/db_clientworklog_selectField.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: ({
            table: firmName, /* if i replace "firmName" with one of the table's names, like "frende", it works (tho it populates immediately onload) */
            column: "project",
            }),
        success: function(data){
            $("#project").html(data);
         }
    });
})
.change();
</script>
```

Comment: this probably isn't the problem, but you should take out the comma at the end of the 'column: "client",' and 'column: "project",' lines since they are at the end of the array. IE can be a real bugger about that.

Comment: Are you sure firmName is not undefined? I would throw an alert into your third change binding right after the $("#firm").val() to make sure it is actually getting a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the code in Chrome, I get 

`Uncaught ReferenceError: clientName is not defined`

when changing the client-field.   Your clientName is not defined as the code stands.

When changing the code as

```
$("#client").change(function () {
    var clientName = "??"; // define the variable
    var firmName = $("#firm").val();
    $("#results").text(firmName);
    $("#client option:selected").each(function () {
        clientName += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
....
```

and it runs just fine for me

Comment: your trigger uses both clientName and firmName -- not sure which one you intend to actually send in your ajax call..

Comment: ah! thanks! i use php a lot, so i forget with javascript that you have to define a variable before you can use it.

Comment: btw i'm actually sending both firmName and clientName because firmName is also the name of the table in the mysql database, then the clientName is also the name of the first column of the table firmName.